# can not compare a datetime variable in sql-server to null value

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to convert a datetime variable in SQL-Server to string and compare it with an empty string:

```
CONVERT(varchar(20), @DATEDEB, 1) =''
```

This is the test I have in my code:

```
IF (@N_CATComp = 4) AND (@EXON='' OR CONVERT(varchar(20), @DATEDEB, 1) ='' OR CONVERT(varchar(20), @DATEFIN, 1) = '')
```

the test works even if datedeb and datefin empty

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the dates to NULL then you can simply try to use the [IS [NOT] NULL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)

> Determines whether a specified expression is NULL.

Something like

```
@myDate IS NULL AND @myDate1 IS NOT NULL
```

By using this you don't have to convert your datetime to a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

OKay , the answer is in sql-server,  @DATEDEB<>'01/01/1900' which is the defult date that sqlç-serveur takes